# run time error "380' in Progress bar in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I've made an Internet Browser in VB 6.0 and i have given a progress bar to it...
when the link is entered and after clicking on "GO." button value of progress bar starts increasing but when it fills completely the ERROR comes..
Run time Error '380':
Invalid Property value.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate Text1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    WebBrowser1.GoBack
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
    WebBrowser1.GoForward
End Sub

Private Sub menuchangetheme_Click()
    CDB1.ShowColor
    Form1.BackColor = CDB1.Color
End Sub

Private Sub menuexit_Click()
    End
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_ProgressChange(ByVal Progress As Long, ByVal ProgressMax As Long)
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    If ProgressBar1.Value <> Val(ProgressBar1.Max) Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + Val(Progress)
        ProgressBar1.Max = ProgressBar1.Value + 1
    Else
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to be adding on the updated progress value rather than replacing it. The progress value should be a percentage so just use 0 to 100 on the progress bar and assign the value directly.

Comment: Oh, and never use the [`End`](http://hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk/index.php?title=End) statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters **Progress** and **ProgressMax** are already numeric so you do not need to convert them. As Deanna pointed out, your code is adding Progress to the Value of the progressbar. The error occurs because you attempt to assign a value greater than the progressbar **Max** property.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_ProgressChange(ByVal Progress As Long, ByVal ProgressMax As Long)

    On Local Error Resume Next 'suppress errors because they are not important enough to display to user

    If Progress > 0 Then                   'the page download is not complete
        ProgressBar1.Min = 0               'not really needed, but also doesn't hurt to set it here
        ProgressBar1.Max = ProgressMax + 1 'needs to be set because the ProgressMax can change every time the event is raised
        ProgressBar1.Value= Progress       'set the displayed value of the progressbar
    Else
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0             'the page load is finished
    End If

End Sub
```